# Why is there a difference of "ML" vs "MLLIB" in Apache Spark's documentation?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to figure out which **pyspark** library to use with Word2Vec and I'm presented with two options according to the pyspark documentation.

> https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-feature-extraction.html#word2vec
>   https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#word2vec

`mllib` seems to be for using RDD's. And `ml` seems to be using "DataFrames".

What is the difference? Shouldn't they both be using RDDs if this is spark under the hood?

What is a "DataFrame" here? As the documentation doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, `mllib` uses `RDD`s and ml uses `dataframe`s. At the beginning, there was only `mllib` because `dataframe`s did not exist in spark. In fact, `ml` is kind of the new `mllib`, if you are new to spark, you should work with `ml` and `dataframe`s.

Answer (score 5):

An RDD is a Read-only partition collection of records. RDD is or was the fundamental data structure of Spark. It allows a programmer to perform in-memory computations on large clusters in a fault-tolerant manner. Thus, speed up the task.

A dataframe on the other hand organizes data into named columns. It is an immutable distributed collection of data. DataFrame in Spark allows developers to impose a structure onto a distributed collection of data, allowing higher-level abstraction.

The two are very different and more details on the two can be found on this link https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset/

`mllib` was in the initial releases of spark as at that time spark was only working with RDDs. Now a lot of Spark coding is done around dataframes, which `ml` supports. Spark has also put `mllib` under maintenance.

> As of Spark 2.0, the RDD-based APIs in the spark.mllib package have
>   entered maintenance mode. The primary Machine Learning API for Spark
>   is now the DataFrame-based API in the spark.ml package.
>
> Q. What are the implications?
>
> MLlib will still support the RDD-based API in spark.mllib with bug
>   fixes. MLlib will not add new features to the RDD-based API. In the
>   Spark 2.x releases, MLlib will add features to the DataFrames-based
>   API to reach feature parity with the RDD-based API. After reaching
>   feature parity (roughly estimated for Spark 2.3), the RDD-based API
>   will be deprecated. The RDD-based API is expected to be removed in
>   Spark 3.0.
>
> Q. Why is MLlib switching to the DataFrame-based API?
>
> DataFrames provide a more user-friendly API than RDDs. The many
>   benefits of DataFrames include Spark Datasources, SQL/DataFrame
>   queries, Tungsten and Catalyst optimizations, and uniform APIs across
>   languages. The DataFrame-based API for MLlib provides a uniform API
>   across ML algorithms and across multiple languages. DataFrames
>   facilitate practical ML Pipelines, particularly feature
>   transformations. See the Pipelines guide for details.
>
> Q. What is “Spark ML”?
>
> “Spark ML” is not an official name but occasionally used to refer to
>   the MLlib DataFrame-based API. This is majorly due to the
>   org.apache.spark.ml Scala package name used by the DataFrame-based
>   API, and the “Spark ML Pipelines” term we used initially to emphasize
>   the pipeline concept.
>
> Q. Is MLlib deprecated?
>
> No. MLlib includes both the RDD-based API and the DataFrame-based API.
>   The RDD-based API is now in maintenance mode. But neither API is
>   deprecated, nor MLlib as a whole.

You will find more details on Sparks official release https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#announcement-dataframe-based-api-is-primary-api